# how to rotate Rectangle shape cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv

I have simple rectangle I just want to rotate this rectangle in any input angle
my code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


imgc = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), np.uint8)


p0 = (100, 100)
p1 = (100 , 150)
p2 = (150, 150)
p3 = (150, 100)

pp = np.array([p0, p1, p2, p3])
cv2.drawContours(imgc, [pp], 0, (155, 155, 155), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("image",imgc)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Does this help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: no ,, I need to know how I can do that in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [Rotation Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). But you need to remember this rotating a point with a given angle (in radians) around the ORIGIN.

You need to move your points to the origin rotate them and move them back same amount.

Here what is would look line when you break down all dot production steps into one equation:

```
def rotate(points, angle):
    ANGLE = np.deg2rad(angle)
    c_x, c_y = np.mean(points, axis=0)
    return np.array(
        [
            [
                c_x + np.cos(ANGLE) * (px - c_x) - np.sin(ANGLE) * (py - c_x),
                c_y + np.sin(ANGLE) * (px - c_y) + np.cos(ANGLE) * (py - c_y)
            ]
            for px, py in points
        ]
    ).astype(int)
```

Please notice: `drawContours` expects points as integers not floats so you need to convert your arrays to `int`.

Here the blue rectangle was the original one and the magenta rectangle is the 45 degrees rotated one:

[image: Rotation Results]

Comment: plz visit my part two if the question :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556993/i-try-to-rotate-rectangle-with-function-but-the-boxes-not-in-correct-position