# I try to rotate rectangle with function but the boxes not in correct position

Tags: python, opencv

the code do rotate for points as angle that I input, but the output of the boxes not in correct arrange ..plz chk my code blow.. I want each box rotate as the angle that I input but in same time I want it in correct lines and columns

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math




def rotate( points, angle):
    ANGLE = np.deg2rad(angle)
    ANGLE = np.deg2rad(angle)
    c_x, c_y = np.mean(points, axis=0)

    return np.array(
        [
            [
                c_x  + math.cos(ANGLE) * (pxl - c_x) - math.sin(ANGLE) * (py - c_x),
                c_y + math.sin(ANGLE) * (pxl - c_y) + math.cos(ANGLE) * (py - c_y)
            ]
            for pxl, py in points
        ]
    ).astype(int)




imgc = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), np.uint8)
box = 0
box2 = 0


for i in range(1,10,1):
    box2 = box2 + 25
    box = 0

    for x in range(1, 10, 1):
        p0 = (box, box2)
        p1 = (0 + box, box2 + 20)
        p2 = (20 + box, box2 + 20)
        p3 = (box + 20, box2)

        box = box + 25

        p0, p1, p2, p3 = rotate((p0, p1, p2, p3), 45)
        pp = np.array([p0, p1, p2, p3])
        cv2.drawContours(imgc, [pp], 0, (255, 255, 255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)



cv2.imshow("image",imgc)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables. You could also run code on few elements (ie. 1 or 2 elements) and then you can calculate rotation on paper and compare with calculations in code. You may need to write `for pxl, py in points` as normal loop so you could add `print()` between calculations. And this is method which you should use to debug your problem before you ask question. BTW: to help you I would have to also do this to find problem but you can do it on your own - and this can learn you how to work with problems.

Comment: Thank you so much ,,, I will contact you for some business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You move to center in wrong way.

In first you substract `c_x` from `px` and `py`.
In second you substract `c_y` from `px` and `py`.

```
... + ... * (pxl - c_x) - ... * (py - c_x),   # only `c_x`
... + ... * (pxl - c_y) - ... * (py - c_y),   # only `c_y`
```

But you should substract `c_x` always only from `px` but not `py`.
And you should substract `c_y` always only from `py` but not `px`.

```
 ... + ... * (px - c_x) - ... * (py - c_y)
 ... + ... * (px - c_x) - ... * (py - c_y)
```

---

```py
def rotate(points, angle):
    ANGLE = np.deg2rad(angle)
    SIN = math.sin(ANGLE)
    COS = math.cos(ANGLE)
    
    c_x, c_y = np.mean(points, axis=0)

    return np.array(
        [
            [
                c_x + COS * (px - c_x) - SIN * (py - c_y),
                c_y + SIN * (px - c_x) + COS * (py - c_y),
            ]
            for px, py in points
        ]
    ).astype(int)
```

Before rotation:

[image]

After rotation:

[image]